# Cell/BE: make use of the SPEs under Linux

Tags: linux, cell, cpu

Currently I'm experimenting with the Cell/BE CPU under Linux. What I'm trying to do is running simulations in the near future, e.g. about the weather or black holes.

Problem is, Linux only discovers the main CPU of the Cell (the PPE), all other SPUs (7 should be available to Linux) are "sleeping". They just don't work out of the box.

What works is the PPE and it's recognized as a two-threaded CPU with one core by the OS. Also, the SPEs are shown at every boot (with small penguins showing a red "PPE" in them), but afterwards are shown nowhere.

Is it possible to "free" these specialised cores for use by the Linux OS? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

As noone seems to be interested or can answer this question I'll provide the details myself.

In fact there exists a workaround:

> First, create an entry point for the SPUFS:
>
> `# sudo mkdir /spu`
>
> Create a mount point for the filesystem so you won’t have to manually mount after a reboot. Add this line to */etc/fstab*
>
> `spufs /spu spufs defaults 0 0`
>
> Now reboot and test to make sure the SPUFS is mounted (in a terminal):
>
> spu-top
>
> You should see the 7 SPEs running with 0% load average.
>
> Now Google for the following package to get the runtime library and headers you need for SPE development:
>
> libspe2-2.3.0.135.tar.gz
>
> You should find it on the first hit. Just unpack, build, and install it:
>
> `./configure`
>
> `make`
>
> `sudo make install`
>
> You can ignore the build warnings (or fix them if you have obsessive compulsive disorder).
>
> You can use pkg-config to find the location of the runtime and headers though they are in /usr/local if I recall.
>
> You of course need the gcc-spe compiler and the rest of the PPU and SPU toolchains but those you can install with apt-get as they are in the repos.

Source: [comment by Exillis via redribbongnulinux.000webhostapp.com](http://redribbongnulinux.000webhostapp.com/feature-requests/#comment-64)